# NameError: name 'root' is not defined in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

Below is the program I am trying to run

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import LabelFrame, Label, Tk#, Canvas
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import os


import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

class GUIDesign():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.initUI(root) 

    def initUI(self,root):
        print ("hello")

    LabelFrameFG="purple"
    LabelFrameBG="SNOW"

    note = Notebook(root)
    tab1 = Frame(note)
    tab6 = Frame(note)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.state('zoomed')
    GUI=GUIDesign(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python\tk.py", line 16, in <module>
class GUIDesign():
File "E:\Python\tk.py", line 35, in GUIDesign
note = Notebook(root)
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

The problem is in importing Notebook? or the class and its function? or python's version problem? Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this program please?

Comment: you have not defined variable **root**

Comment: `def __init__(self,root):`  will only allow root variable to be used in that function. For `note = Notebook(root)` this, you need to define **root** outside the function.

Comment: in your code `root` is a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define root as the global variable. Your code should be like this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import LabelFrame, Label, Tk#, Canvas
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import os


import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

root = Tk()

class GUIDesign():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.initUI(root) 

    def initUI(self,root):
        print ("hello")

    LabelFrameFG="purple"
    LabelFrameBG="SNOW"

    note = Notebook(root)
    tab1 = Frame(note)
    tab6 = Frame(note)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.state('zoomed')
    GUI=GUIDesign(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The notebook was unable to access the root as its local variable. I have just defined as a global variable. Hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: yeah. Thanks a ton. It is working. I was of the opinion that using it as global wasn't a good way of programming. But this works for me. So thanks :)